# File not found error when saving CSV in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to save my dataframe in PySpark to a CSV on Windows from a Jupyter Notebook but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
```

I am using this code to do so:

```py
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("filtered.csv")
```

How do I fix this? I notice that in the directory, a new folder "filtered.csv" (not file, an actual folder) is created instead, and it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a problem on Windows systems due to the inability of Spark to utilize the native POSIX file system saving.

You need to make sure you have Hadoop downloaded and that you have an environment variable pointing to it, and also that you have `Winutils.exe` in its bin folder to allow Spark to save the file.

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/how-to-install-and-run-pyspark-on-windows/